# Как правильно написать - "Ваша фамилия, имя, отчество" или "Ваши фамилия, имя, отчество"

Tags: прилагательные

Добрый день.
Подскажите, как правильно написать "Ваша фамилия, имя, отчество" или "Ваши фамилия, имя, отчество"?

Comment: Помнится, на вступительном экзамене по литературе и русскому языку в 1954-м году в сочинении на свободную тему я написал: "...действительных равенства, братства и свободы". На "устной" литературе экзаменатор сообщила, что мне поставили 4. "Почему?",- спросил я.- "Надо было написать: "действительного" - "Но я же хотел подчеркнуть, что дейстивтельно не только равенство, но и братсво и свобода" - "У нас по Вашему сочинению состоялся целый консилиум. Решили, что Вы сделали ошибку". Из-за этой ошибки я не попал на тот факультет, куда сдавал экзамены, недополучив 1 балл. Консилиум сломал мне жизнь:

Comment: Видимо, Вы сдавали вступительный экзамен по литературе и русскому языку  представителям "советского народа" (цит. по преамбуле последней конституции СССР).

Comment: Галактион, а кому еще можно было сдавать экзамен в 1954 году?

Comment: Например, таджикам.

Comment: "Ваши фамилия, имя, отчество" = "Ваша фамилия, Ваше имя, Ваше отчество"

Comment: Ваша, как твоя фамилия? А имя?

Answer (score 3):

Чаще встречается вариант "Ваши фамилия, имя, отчество".

По общим правилам здесь возможны обе формы. В пользу ед.числа говорит тот факт, что определение относится ко всем существительным, и это не вызывает сомнения. Выбор варианта с формой мн. числа, скорее всего, объясняется тем, что существительные относятся к разным родам.

Comment: София, Вас не затруднит указать источник, рассматривающий форму множественного числа как нормативную?

Comment: Я смотрела эту тему по учебнику Розенталя "Современный русский язык" (параграф  252 "Согласование определений с однородными членами предложений). Но там не указывается норма, просто даются рассуждения о факторах, влияющих на выбор. Здесь мы имеем ситуацию, когда приходится выбирать между смысловой точностью и грамматической сочетаемостью. В нашем случае следует учитывать, что существительные составляют единую смысловую группу (мн.число). В то же время в косвенных падежах на первое место может выйти грамматический фактор (ед.ч.): укажите вашу фамилию, имя, отчество.

Comment: Как оказалось, есть два учебника с таким названием, в числе авторов которых Розенталь. Однако в них я почему-то не могу найти ни указанного параграфа, ни информации, которая, по Вашим словам, размещена в нем. София, простите за назойливость, но не могли бы Вы указать издание или дать ссылку на эл. версию учебника?

Comment: Изд.4, Москва, "Высшая школа", 1984 год. Под редакцией Розенталя, для студентов вызов, обучающихся по специальности "Журналистика". Он, по-моему, и после переиздавался.

Comment: В пользу множественного числа говорит стиль речи: официально-деловой. На это указывает тот же Розенталь в "Практической стилистике"

Comment: > Изд.4, Москва, "Высшая школа", 1984 год. Под редакцией Розенталя, для студентов вызов, обучающихся по специальности "Журналистика". Он, по-моему, и после переиздавался.

Спасибо, что не проигнорировали мою просьбу, но оказалось проще забыть, чем найти этот учебник.))

Answer (score 3):

В ["Справочнике по правописанию, произношению, литературному редактированию" Розенталя, в параграфе 195](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm#з_05), есть такие строки: "Определение, относящееся к двум или нескольким существительным – однородным членам, ставится в форме единственного числа, если по смыслу сочетания ясно, что определение относится не только к ближайшему существительному, но и к последующим, например: *написать **свой** адрес, имя, отчество*".

Правда, следующий абзац ("форма числа определения может зависеть от формы падежа определяемых существительных; ср.: Можно представить себе, каким громовым ударом разразилось это письмо над моим отцом и матерью (Аксаков). – Здесь жили мои отец и мать (Чехов) (в первом случае форма косвенного падежа с предлогом, во втором – форма именительною падежа)") не дает нам испытать радость чистого знания, поскольку сообщает о нормативных вариантах согласования, не подчиняющихся описанной выше закономерности. Однако, за "вашу фамилию, имя и отчество", я думаю, можно быть спокойным.

Comment: Да, исчерпывающей достаточности ради необходимо отметить, что в параграфе, на который я ссылалась, присутствует, - правда, без "рассуждений о факторах, влияющих на выбор" - замечание, которое, я полагаю, имеет отношение к рассматриваемому случаю, а именно: "Из двух вариантов: ***Мой** отец с матерью уехали в деревню* и ***Мои** отец с матерью уехали в деревню* – предпочтительнее первый".
Хотя в справочнике ясно сказано, какой вариант предпочтительнее, неясным становится другой вопрос: зачем в параграфе первый пункт?