# Число аббревиатуры ФИО

Tags: род

Какой вариант верен:

1. Записывать свои ФИО
2. Записывать своё ФИО?

Comment: Да, спасибо: поправил!

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/29823

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как правильно написать - "Ваша фамилия, имя, отчество" или "Ваши фамилия, имя, отчество"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/29823/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%92%d0%b0%d1%88%d0%b0-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%92%d0%b0%d1%88%d0%b8-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d0%be)

Answer (score 2):

Любопытный вопрос.

Слово **фио** имело все шансы закрепиться в русском языке (как это произошло со словом "вуз") в качестве существительного, образованного от аббревиатуры **ФИО**. Тогда это было бы несклоняемое существительное среднего рода. В качестве примера приведу цитату из Нацкорпуса:

> На пересылке грузный, пухлый, по-коровьи пыхтящий писарь отнял у меня
> военкоматскую бумагу, опросил **моё фио** и занес его в какой-то форменный
> журнал. (Виктор Астафьев, Последний поклон) [на всякий случай уточню, что это слова автора]

В.А. Успенский [говорит](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=qAX6jcySjYsC&pg=PA196&dq=%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B+%22%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BE%22+%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B7+%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi7-5ir18XuAhWFuIsKHWshDmUQ6AEwAHoECAAQAg#v=onepage&q=%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B%20%22%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BE%22%20%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B7%20%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5&f=false) о переходе **фио** в разряд несклоняемых существительных среднего рода как о состоявшемся факте:

> Несклоняемое существительное среднего рода **фио** прошло ту же эволюцию от аббревиатуры **ФИО**, что и существительное **вуз** от аббревиатуры **ВУЗ**.

Однако словари слово **фио** пока не фиксируют. Что касается **фио** в словаре Лопатина, то там совсем другое значение, которое знакомо только специалистам по международной торговле и морской логистике (условия фрахтования **фио** [от английского *Free In and Out*]).

Comment: *условия фрахтования фио* - хоть один документ на русском можете покахать с этой аббревиатурой? Я спрашивал (давно) у юристов и торговцев - они не знают такого. ПС словарь морских терминов приводит FIFO - погрузка и выгрузка за счет отправителя. Но на **английском**. http://advanceshipping.ru/fifo_free_in_free_out/

Comment: *В.А. Успенский говорит о переходе фио* - хорошо бы на первоисточник посмотреть. Всё что нашел - это упоминание этой фразы вне контекста в некой книге "В.А. Успенский, Труды по нематематике".

Comment: @behemothus Ссылка на Успенского не помещается в комментарий. Я добавил её в ответ. Посмотрите там параграф 19 и окружающий контекст. То же можно найти в книге "Апология математики", я бы порекомендовал её независимо от данной темы.

Comment: *Я добавил её в ответ.*  - не вижу.

Comment: @behemothus По поводу "фио" посмотрите [здесь](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_economic_law/16774/%D0%A3%D0%A1%D0%9B%D0%9E%D0%92%D0%98%D0%95) (там более 10 источников на выбор). Я не хотел бы спорить по поводу специфики употребления этого термина в логистике, но считаю, что в словаре Лопатина подразумевается не ошибка, а именно этот термин.

Comment: @behemothus Сейчас в ответе в предложении "В.А. Успенский говорит" слово "говорит" подчёркнуто как гиперссылка. Нужно нажать на неё мышкой. (Кажется, я правил на другой странице и не сохранил её. Сейчас должно быть нормально.)

Comment: *По поводу "фио" посмотрите здесь* - С этим ясно. Спасибо.

Comment: *Я добавил её в ответ.* - Каюсь. Видел этот сборник, не посмотрел на выходные данные. Если верить тексту, статья(?) была опубликована в "Вопросах филологии" в давнопрошедшие годы... Это снимает вопросы. Спасибо.

Comment: К какому разделу языкознания можно отнести мой вопрос, как его маркировать? Орфография?

Answer (score 1):

Хоть и дубликат, но отвечу.
ФИО как аббревиатура от "Фамилия, Имя, Отчество" словарями не фиксируется, поэтому род (именно род! - зря поправили) и число определить не представляется возможным. В целом же, как и в случае любой другой неустоявшейся аббревиатуры, естественно считать ФИО по роду составляющих - то есть в данном случае множественным числом без выделения категории рода. Использование же этой аббревиатуры как слова среднего рода выглядит просторечным

Примечание.
Лопатин приводит слово "фио" как слово среднеего рода со значением "вид сделки".
http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BE

Подозреваю, что это ошибка, подобный термин в юридических и бизнес-сферах неизвестен. В любом случае к вопросу о роде аббревиатуры это отношения не имеет.

(+) ====

grizzly убедил меня, что у Лопатина воспроизведена форма, которая вошла уже вошла в другие словари. То есть, если даже и ошибка, то не лопатинская. На основной мой текст никак не влияет.

Comment: А почему "Фамилия, Имя, Отчество" пишутся с заглавной буквы?

Answer (score 0):

Записывать свои фамилию, имя и отчество.

Записывать <strike>своё</strike> фамилию ...

Первый вариант должен быть верен т.к. записывать что? Записывать свои расшифрованные инициалы.

Но не <strike>своё инициалы</strike>.